# animationend event also also fires on end of animations of child elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with an animation.

I've attached an animationend event listener to this div.

This div also has a child element with an animation.

For some reason the animationend event fires when the childelement's animation finishes as well.

Why is this? Is there a way to get around this? I would like the animationend event only to run when the element that I attached the eventlistener to finishes.

```js
document.querySelector('.outer').addEventListener('animationend',function () {
  console.log('done')
})
```

```css
body {
  height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
}

.outer {
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:black;
  animation:spin 2s 
}

.inner {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:red;
    animation:spin 2s 2s 
}



@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform:rotate(0)
  }
  to {
    transform:rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

**Trying with id instead. Still no luck**

```js
document.querySelector('#outer').addEventListener('animationend',function () {
  console.log('done')
})
```

```css
body {
  height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
}

#outer {
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:black;
  animation:spin 2s 
}

.inner {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:red;
    animation:spin 2s 2s 
}



@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform:rotate(0)
  }
  to {
    transform:rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m curious, if you use an #id on class outer, will that exclude the child .inner element?

Comment: @zipzit Just added a snippet using id. Still the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the event's target is the element the listener is attached to. The event handler is also called when the animation on a child element ends because the `animationend` event bubbles.

```js
document.querySelector('.outer').addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
    if(e.target === this)  console.log('done')
})
```

```js
document.querySelector('.outer').addEventListener('animationend',function (e) {
    if(e.target === this)  console.log('done')
})
```

```css
body {
  height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
}

.outer {
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:black;
  animation:spin 2s 
}

.inner {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:red;
    animation:spin 2s 2s 
}



@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform:rotate(0)
  }
  to {
    transform:rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works. But doesn't calling `e.stopPropagation()` prevent the bubbling?

Comment: But why doesn't*

Comment: @BorisGrunwald It does prevent the bubbling: https://jsfiddle.net/0trxeL65/